Error while fitting Bayesian cox pH model using rstanarm package in r
I was fitting the Cox PH model using the Bayesian approach in R software (Using rstanarm package). It shows mean error message "could not find function "stan_surv"".
 bayes_cox <- stan_surv(Surv(time, status) ~ Sex + Treatment + Stage,data = df,method = "breslow")

Error in stan_surv(Surv(time, status) ~ Sex + Treatment + Stage, data = df,  :

  could not find function "stan_surv"


https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/issues/500#issuecomment-1203904085

Welcome to SO.  @Phil has nailed it.  Assuming, of course, that you have library(rstanarm) before you call stan_surv... :-)  Without a minimal reproducible example, we can't be sure...
